# Sort keys of associative array with usort

Tags: php, sorting

I have an associative array with the `$category` (title of the category) as key and the `$auditElement` as value:

```
foreach ($auditElements as $auditElement) {
    $category = $auditElement->getAuditCategory()->getTitle();
    if (!array_key_exists($category, $groupedEntries)) {
        $groupedEntries[$category] = [];
        $auditCategories[$category] = $auditElement->getAuditCategory()->getSequenceIndex();
    }

    $groupedEntries[$category][] = $auditElement;
}
```

Now I want to sort this array `$groupedEntries` by the `sequenceIndex` of the category. Therefore I have saved the `sequenceIndex` of the category in an extra array `$auditCategories` with the `$category` as key and the `sequenceIndex` as value.

My idea was to use `usort` or `uasort`to sort the `$groupedEntries` by the sequenceIndex:

```
uasort($groupedEntries, function ($cat1, $cat2) use ($auditCategories) {
    $idx1 = $auditCategories[$cat1];
    $idx2 = $auditCategories[$cat2];
    return ($idx1 == $idx2) ? 0 : ($idx1 > $idx2]) ? 1 : -1;
});
```

But I get an error because the elements in the comparison function aren't the single array elements but the value array associated with the key:

> Illegal offset type

Comment: `$groupedEntries` is array of arrays. So, `$cat1` (and `$cat2`) is subarray.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As `$groupedEntries` is array of arrays, `$cat1` (and `$cat2`) are subarrays. Instead, try [`uksort`](http://php.net/uksort), here, you will receive **keys** as comparing values:

```
uksort($groupedEntries, function ($cat1, $cat2) use ($auditCategories) {
    $idx1 = $auditCategories[$cat1];
    $idx2 = $auditCategories[$cat2];
    return ($idx1 == $idx2) ? 0 : ($idx1 > $idx2]) ? 1 : -1;
    // you can replace last line with
    // return $idx1 - $idx2; 
    // or if you want to be more precise and you have php7
    // return $idx1 <=> $idx2;
});
```